# How to use Thread.sleep() effectively in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I use multi thread and when I use multi thread, cpu usage is 100% over.

multi thread count is variable. sometimes count range between 200 and 400

so I need that cpu usage decrease in my application.

```
private void _ThreadWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            var DataSpots = e.Argument as Dictionary<PointF, List<LogScanCollection>>;
            if (DataSpots != null)
            {
                var UpLoadThread = new Thread[DataSpots.Count];

                for (int i = 0; i < UpLoadThread.Length; i++)
                {
                    int temp = i;
                    var item = DataSpots.ElementAt(i);
                    var ItemKey = item.Key;
                    var ItemValue = item.Value;
                    UpLoadThread[temp] = new Thread(() => DataUpload(ItemKey, ItemValue, UpLoadThread[temp]));
                    UpLoadThread[temp].IsBackground = true;
                }
                foreach (Thread t in UpLoadThread)
                {
                    t.Start();
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }

                foreach (Thread t in UpLoadThread)
                {
                    t.Join();
                }
            }
        }
```

Process Thread method

```
private void DataUpload(PointF ItemKey, List<LogScanCollection> ItemValue, Thread thread)
        {
            object db = new object();
            lock (db)
            {
                bool DmsXYExist = DmsXYKeyExist(ItemKey);
                string mtime = ItemValue[0].MeasTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                PointF GPS = ItemValue[0].GPS;
                if (DmsXYExist)
                {
                    if (ItemValue.Count > 1)
                    {
                        var DataList = GetCalMergeData(ItemValue);
                        var DbData = GetDbData(ItemKey);

                        List<double> min = ChangeDataList(DataList.Min, DbData.Min, DataCalType.Min);
                        List<double> max = ChangeDataList(DataList.Max, DbData.Max, DataCalType.Max);
                        List<double> aver = ChangeDataList(DataList.Aver, DbData.Aver, DataCalType.Aver);
                        List<double> exp = ChangeDataList(DataList.Exp, DbData.Exp, DataCalType.Aver);
                        if (!CheckDupDataFromTime(mtime, "vmmin"))
                        {
                            UpdateDataQuery("vmmin", GPS, ItemKey, min, mtime, "min");
                            UpdateDataQuery("vmmax", GPS, ItemKey, max, mtime, "max");
                            UpdateDataQuery("vmaver", GPS, ItemKey, aver, mtime, "aver");
                            UpdateDataQuery("expidx", GPS, ItemKey, exp, mtime, "exp");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var Fs = GetFieldStrengthArray(ItemValue[0].Data3G);
                        var Ei = GetExpIdxArray(ItemValue[0].Data3G);
                        var DbData = GetDbData(ItemKey);
                        List<double> min = ChangeDataList(Fs, DbData.Min, DataCalType.Min);
                        List<double> max = ChangeDataList(Fs, DbData.Max, DataCalType.Max);
                        List<double> aver = ChangeDataList(Fs, DbData.Aver, DataCalType.Aver);
                        List<double> exp = ChangeDataList(Ei, DbData.Exp, DataCalType.Aver);

                        if (!CheckDupDataFromTime(mtime, "vmmin"))
                        {
                            UpdateDataQuery("vmmin", GPS, ItemKey, min, mtime, "min");
                            UpdateDataQuery("vmmax", GPS, ItemKey, max, mtime, "max");
                            UpdateDataQuery("vmaver", GPS, ItemKey, aver, mtime, "aver");
                            UpdateDataQuery("expidx", GPS, ItemKey, exp, mtime, "exp");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    InsertDmsXYTableKey(ItemKey, mtime);
                    if (ItemValue.Count > 1)
                    {
                        var DataList = GetCalMergeData(ItemValue);
                        InsertDataQuery("vmmin", GPS, ItemKey, DataList.Min, mtime);
                        InsertDataQuery("vmmax", GPS, ItemKey, DataList.Max, mtime);
                        InsertDataQuery("vmaver", GPS, ItemKey, DataList.Aver, mtime);
                        InsertDataQuery("expidx", GPS, ItemKey, DataList.Exp, mtime);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        InsertDataQuery("vmmin", GPS, ItemKey, GetFieldStrengthArray(ItemValue[0].Data3G), mtime);
                        InsertDataQuery("vmmax", GPS, ItemKey, GetFieldStrengthArray(ItemValue[0].Data3G), mtime);
                        InsertDataQuery("vmaver", GPS, ItemKey, GetFieldStrengthArray(ItemValue[0].Data3G), mtime);
                        InsertDataQuery("expidx", GPS, ItemKey, GetExpIdxArray(ItemValue[0].Data3G), mtime);

                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < ItemValue.Count; i++)
                {
                    string mtime1 = ItemValue[i].MeasTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    double rbw = ItemValue[i].Data3G.Frequency[1] - ItemValue[0].Data3G.Frequency[0];
                    int length = ItemValue[i].Data3G.Frequency.Length;
                    if (!CheckDupDataFromTime(mtime1, "tr3g"))
                    {
                        InsertTraceData("tr3g", mtime1, ItemValue[i].GPS, ItemKey, ItemValue[i].Data3G.MergeByteXYZ, rbw, length);
                    }
                    if (!CheckDupDataFromTime(mtime1, "tr6g"))
                    {
                        InsertTraceData("tr6g", mtime1, ItemValue[i].GPS, ItemKey, ItemValue[i].Data6G, rbw, length);
                    }

                }
                _ThreadWorker.ReportProgress(0);

                if(thread.IsAlive)
                {
                    thread.Abort();
                }
            }


        }
```

please let me know how to decrease cpu usage and use Thread effectively

thanks!

Comment: if you don't want to use all your cores, then don't multi-thread! Simple!

Comment: `sometimes count range between 200 and 400` I hope you're not talking about the number of threads, here

Comment: You do know that each thread consumes in excess of 1MB of RAM? So 400 threads could be half a gigibyte or more. To get maximum throughput you should limit your threads to the number of cores you have - most likely 4 or 8.

Comment: Also your code is probably a complete waste of time. You are trying to lock on `db` - presumably to prevent multiple threads from entering the code in `DataUpload` at the same time. Right now because you new up a lock variable for each call to `DataUpload` it has no effect, but if you used a lock variable properly then you're effectively single-threading the code.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of io bound work I  your DataUpload method in which case converting the blocking io to async methods and awaiting the results will allow parallelism without thread overhead.

Comment: @Enigmativity this program process in server computer. server comupter ram is 32GB; so How many thread number this program?

Comment: @Enigmativity I use lock on db For each thread Can not access db

Comment: @HighEndGuy - You have a fundamental problem - if you want to prevent multiple threads accessing the database then you're effectively running a single thread program and trying to introduce threads will be an overhead with no benefit.

Comment: @Enigmativity I know your mean. I have created complicated calculation program. so if i use single thread, program calculation is very slow. So I want to know best way that prevent multiple thread and fast calculation speed.... Thanks your command.

Comment: Have you tried to profile DataUpload() to find out what lines take most of the time?

Comment: @alexm Maybe I exactly don't know how to use thread. So If you have Multi Thread Source example and website, please give me information. Thanks your command. Have a good time!

Comment: `Sleep` method is wasting of CPU ^)

Comment: @HighEndGuy - You won't get a good example of how to use threads that will help you. Threading is hard and is very dependent on the specific problem at hand. You need to break your problem into separate reads, calculations, and writes, before you can hope to introduce threads.